# Why did I not receive "revival" badge?

Tags: discussion

The revival badge says ...

Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more

See this post ...

[Docker Hub Automated Build - Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328166/docker-hub-automated-build-tagging/31538378#31538378)

Question was asked on Aug 14

I answer on July 15

My score is 11 - my answer is the top answer

Why did I not receive this badge? thanks

Comment: Your answer was not the first answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least two other answers that were posted before yours and more than 30 days after the question was asked that now have a score of at least 2. There is also an answer that was posted on the *same day* the question was asked, that now has a score of 4. Either the Revival badge was awarded to the first of those two other answers to reach a score of 2, or it was never awarded via that question in the first place.